# Good architecture to shift a WPF desktop application to Client Server technology

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

I have a working WPF application that works on a single PC. I have used SQL server database, Entity Framework to communicate with database
and RDLC reporting in the application. Now the requirement has arrived to make this application work on the local company network where multiple users (normally around 25 at max) will access application depending upon there roles and permissions set. I did some R&D on this and used primarily the architecture mentioned here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/434282/A-N-Tier-Architecture-Sample-with-ASP-NET-MVC-WCF, and after doing so, I have made a paper design/architecture of the application that will look like this

> **A WCF service running on a high end server within the company network**

1. GPC.Service itself - defines the protocol to connect to the service
   and all other necessary information
2. GPC.Algorithm - will be the main business logic layer that will
   contain the logic and will be interface to the clients for calling
   the database layer methods
3. GPC.Persistance - will have actual database interaction methods like
   fetching/storing/updating/deleting records in the database
4. GPC.Data - This will contain the edmx schema for the Entity
   Framwework
5. GPC.Entites - This will contain the entities of the database schema
   and addional partial classes

**

> **Clients:**

The client will a WPF Application based on MVVM pattern for now (may be in future we will need to move to the Web application but   not required for now).  Main components of the application are:

1. Import from excel: Currently all data is in Excel files. All that
   data needs to be imported into the system.
2. Edit/Update/Delete: Once data is imported, allow interface to user
   to edit/update/delete records
3. Generate reprots (using RDLC for this)
4. Users/Roles management etc.

> **Shared:**
>   This is a library that contains differnet miscelenious classes like code to read excel file, Handle errors, Collections that will   be bind to the UI etc.

**DB context: Will be created in a using statement inside the Persistance layer for each method to ensure no stale information is left.**

Does this architecure follow the n-tier architecture and is it flexible? What improvements are required in this and please guide me how to improve whatever issues are there. I want to make sure this is a good architecture before I go ahead and change my existing application.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your are on the correct path however you may be over engineering in some areas.

I think to a large degree the EntityFramework deals with the Entities, Data and Persistence layers for you. Implementing them yourself may be overkill unless you are looking to ultimately replace EntityFramework with some other ORM system.

You are eluding to SOA (Service Orientated Architecture) here with your GPC.Services library. Here you need to look at how you can break down your service layer into one or more atmoic services which will serve the client application. There are a number of ways of going about this and would depend largely on how you plan to use the service layer going forward. Take a look at RESTful services which breaks down the services layer nicely and will guide you into building neat atmoic services. Check out the Asp.net Web API for this.

I think what you are looking for in your GPC.Alogrithms library is really a domain model. A domain model encapsulates all your business logic and allows you to perform state changes on your objects via public functions which you expose. With this in mind the layers of the system would appear as follows:

Persistence (EF) -> Domain Model -> Service Layer -> DTO (Data Transfer Objects) -> Client

The DTO objects mentioned above would be a set of POCO (Plain Old C# Objects) which are responsible for delivering data to and from your client. You need this since serializing and desalinizing your domain objects will become problematic due to back references and other encapsulation issues. Putting DTO's in place will enforce a context boundary which is once of the tenets of SOA - "Boundarys are explicit", see [this for more info on soa](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikegil/archive/2005/01/03/345861.aspx)

With respect to the client side it seems like you are on track. What you may want to do is refactor you current client application so that all data queries are consolidated into a single layer. So when the time comes you will just replace that layer with the service implementation.

Answer (score 0):

this makes perfect sense. (try to build it TDD style)

in order to make your life a bit easier with the client versions management consider to use ClickOnce installer to enforce the latest version installations on your users computers (this headache will be gone once you will move it to be a web app).